# Ordenar un array de fechas en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, date

Tengo este array:

`let arrayFechas = [2016-11-21 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-28 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-22 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-23 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-18 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-25 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-19 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-26 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-20 23:00:00 +0000, 2016-11-27 23:00:00 +0000]`

Y lo que quiero, es poder ordenarlo por fecha ascendente. Tengo este código, pero me da error:

```
arrayfechas.sort({ $0.date.compare($1.date) == ComparisonResult.orderAscending })
```

Este es el error que me da:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Utilizo `swift 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tanto si es un array de fechas en formato texto como si es un array de `NSDate` lo único que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
let orderedDates = arrayFechas.sorted()
```

Lo que tienes que saber, que el array tal como lo has pasado no es ninguno de los dos (te faltarían las comillas para cada fecha)

Te dejo la documentación por si acaso (aunque con hacer un simple clic la puedes ver)
https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/joinedsequence/1688956-sorted

Comment: Puedes añadir la documentacion de `sorted()`? No conozco swift pero ese metodo tiene pinta de devolver `bool` ya que es participio, no verbo infinitivo

Comment: @lois6b no devuelve un `bool`, devuelve un nuevo array ordenado

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/joinedsequence/1688956-sorted

Comment: gracias, pero es mas util si lo [añades](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/34990/edit) a tu respuesta y no en un comentario

Comment: Ya lo tienes, aunque era muy simple ver la documentación desde XCode...

Comment: Si pero nunca está de más poner referencias a lo que dices